# How to compare elements with the value of [ ]

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbytagname

I'm trying to get the counts of `<tr>` tag from which contained in `<th>`

for example there's these tags inside a table :

```
<th><tr></tr></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
```

the javascript :

```
var table = document.getElementById(tableId);    
var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
var thead = tbody.getElementsByTagName("th");
var rowCount = 0;

for (i = 0; i < thead.length; i++) {
    if (thead[i].getElementsByTag("tr") === 'unidentified') rowCount++;
}
```

thead variable value should be = [tr], [ ], [ ], [ ]

but the rowCount value is 4, it should've been 1

I'd tried to figure what is the actual value of [ ] //the seemingly empty element

I'd tried comparing thead[i].getElementsByTag("tr") with null, empty, "", "[]", "[ ]"
but the results is false

Comment: `thead` and `th` are two different things. A `th` element should not contain `tr` elements. Normally, `thead` contains `tr`s that contain `th`s. The browser might try to normalize malformed markup like this.

Comment: You can use jQuery

    `$('#'+tableId+" > tr").size()`

Comment: @Narek Have you seen a jQuery tag?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns an empty NodeList if no elements are found, not `undefined` (and certainly not `'unidentified'`). So your check should be something like `if (thead[i].getElementsByTagName("tr").length > 0)`.

Comment: You should not work with invalid HTML, the results will be different in every browser, depending how it handles such invalid HTML.

Comment: @bazmegakapa We're all going to die after that comment? Oh my God, what I've done...

Comment: Some things you should read: [Table-related tags in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html), [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName)

Comment: @Narek jQuery is not a magic wand that will clean up your invalid markup. And sometimes it does not hurt if you know what goes on in the background. (and by the way, the jQuery snippet you posted does not do what the OP asked for, but this is off-topic here)

Comment: thanks guys, and @bazmegakapa (thead[i].getElementsByTagName("tr").length > 0) theadrows ++; work just fine